# Why Are My Font Awesome Icons Not Centering?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to center Font Awesome icons and it works. The only problem is that when I set the font size to over 24, the icons shift to the right instead of centering. Any help is appreciated. Also, for some reason JSFiddle isn't showing Font Awesome, sorry about that.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/598jgszk/

```
<head>
    <!--Default Stuff-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>HighAbyss</title>

    <!--Script Links-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <!--Stylesheet Links-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--Font Links-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!--Website Sidebar-->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
/* Default Stuff */
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

/* Sidebar Menu */
#sidebar {
    background:rgb(41,41,41);
    width:60px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:60px;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

ul li {
    list-style:none;
    height:60px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #111;
}

ul li a {
    color:white;
    padding:19px;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

Comment: A relative path in JS fiddle is based on that site: jsfiddle.net/css/font-awesome.min.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the `padding` given to the `a` tag. When you increase the font-size, the icon stays centered to the `a` but the `a` tag flows out of the `li`, and it seems like it is not centered.

Just edit this padding in your code and make it zero. Also using `display:block;` and defining width and height to be `100%` will make the `a` to fill the entire `li`, and the entire `li` will be clickable

```
ul li a {
    color:white;
    padding:0;
    font-size:30px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/598jgszk/2/) and below is the working code:

```css
/* Default Stuff */
* {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 text-decoration:none;
 list-style:none;
 font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

/* Sidebar Menu */
#sidebar {
 background:rgb(41,41,41);
 width:60px;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:60px;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
}

ul {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}

ul li {
 list-style:none;
 height:60px;
 border-bottom:2px solid #111;
}

ul li a {
 color:white;
 padding:0;
 font-size:30px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>HighAbyss</title>

  <!--Script Links-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

  <!--Stylesheet Links-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/style.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!--Font Links-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 <body>
  <!--Website Sidebar-->
  <div id="sidebar">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Ok but the only problem is I want to keep the padding so I can click on the whole square and it will still redirect me to a link. Is there any other way to make the whole square clickable and direct to the same place as the icon without the padding?

Comment: ok, I updated my answer and changed only the css of `a` tag. also please dont forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use center tag.

```
<center><p>This text is in center</p>
 </center>
```

Comment: Isn't the center tag outdated? And also the center tag has the same problem as what I commented below.